# Laravel / Vue - App.js difference between import and require

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Are there any significant difference between these two syntax?

```
Vue.component('base-table', () => import('./components/BaseTable.vue'))
Vue.component('base-table', require('./components/BaseTable.vue').default);
```

Is one or the other affects the loading performance of an application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Webpack docs:

[require](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#require)

> Synchronously retrieve the exports from another module. The compiler will ensure that the dependency is available in the output bundle

[import()](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-1)

> Dynamically load modules. Calls to import() are treated as split points, meaning the requested module and its children are split out into a separate chunk.

Simply 1st puts your `BaseTable.vue` component into separate JS bundle (file) which will be requested by a browser at the moment component is rendered 1st time. Good for components/parts of app which are not needed immediately (per-route code splitting) or only for some users (admins for example). Your base bundle size is smaller and thus parsed faster by the browser -> better initial loading performance...

*Declaimer: Commenting from Vue/Webpack POV. I know nothing about Laravel except it's PHP thing...*